# HTML5 machine unique ID

Tags: html, uniqueidentifier

Is it possible to uniquely identify a machine within HTML5?
I need to identify the different machines on which the code is running.

Comment: HTML is **markup**. How would you want to identify unique machines with that?

Comment: @Linus Kleen thank you, I am new to HTML5 and I thought there could be some special tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer. I will use non-transient information to uniquely assign an ID to each machine.
Did someone else use this method?

Comment: Why not have the user log in? Or have you app store stuff in localStorage and read it out again when your app starts. Put a 'unique' id that gets generated from your server.

Comment: @tjameson Yes, this is my thinking, too, to use the app store (the non-transient information).